# Interaction turns off footnote in table

Tags: tables, context, interaction

If I use `\setupinteraction` in my document, my footnote in the header of my table disappears. If I turn off `\setupinteraction`, the footnote reappears. Is there a way to have interaction enabled and show the footnote in the table as well.

Below is the MWE:

```
% Allow colors
\setupcolors[state=start]
\definecolor [DCMBlue][r=0.149, g=0.27, b=0.407]
\definecolor[DCMred][r=1, g=0, b=0]


% %Setup TABLE's****************************************
% setup for all cells
\setupTABLE[r][each][style=\tfx, foregroundcolor=DCMBlue, align=center,frame=off]

% setup table head
\setupTABLE[r][first]
  [background=color,
   backgroundcolor=DCMBlue,
   foregroundcolor=white,
   style=\tf]


% Setup bullets
\setupitemize[headstyle=bold,margin=4em, inbetween={\blank[small]}]

\setupinteraction
  [state=start,
  color=DCMBlue,
  contrastcolor=DCMBlue,
  style=bold]


\starttext
\startchapter[
  title={First Chapter}]

  This is a footnote\footnote{this is a document footnote}
\startplacetable[title=New Table]
\bTABLE[split=repeat]% head on every page, stretch columns
\setupTABLE[c][1][width=5em]
\setupTABLE [c][1][align=flushleft]
%
% IMPORTANT: use \bTH ... \eTH to enclose the head|next cells
\bTABLEhead
\bTR
\bTH  Year  \eTH
\bTH  Jan-Jun \eTH
\bTH Jul-Dec \eTH
\bTH Year    \eTH
\bTH Cum     \eTH
\bTH Bench Mark\footnote{This is a table footnote} \eTH
\eTR
\eTABLEhead

%
% the table body (main part)
%
\bTABLEbody
%


\bTR
  \bTC 2030 \eTC
  \bTC 1.9\%  \eTC
  \bTC 6.0\% \eTC
 \bTC  5.1\% \eTC
 \bTC  5.1\% \eTC
 \bTC  11.3\%\eTC
\eTR

%
\eTABLEbody
%
% the table foot
%
\bTABLEfoot
\bTR
  \bTC   \eTC
   \bTC[nc=3,align=flushright]  Compound Return \eTC
  \bTC  3.9\% \eTC
  \bTC  8.5\% \eTC
\eTR
\eTABLEfoot
%
\eTABLE
\stopplacetable
\stopchapter
\stoptext
```

Comment: a) Only local notes can be used in a float without problems. b) Your example is far from minimal.

Comment: @Metafox: Thanks for your comment. If I add `\startlocalfootnotes` before the `\startplacetable` and add `\placelocalfootnotes` and `\stoplocalfootnotes` after `\eTABLE` but before `\stopplacetable`, the footnote appears under the table but the superscript in the table does not appear.  Therefore, it does not seem to make any difference whether I use `\localfootnotes` or not.

Answer (score 3):

Your footnote marking is there.  Try for example

```
\setupinteraction
  [state=start,
   color=DCMBlue,
   contrastcolor=red, % <-- Well, duh
   style=bold]
```

As a matter of fact you can't see `DCMBlue` on top of `DCMBlue`.  You would have noticed if you created a minimal example, which is how I found out.

[image]

Comment: Henri:Thank you. I hadn't realised that the superscript was a link and ,therefore, would be controlled by `contrastcolor`. It makes perfect sense now. That causes me another problem though. I want my `contrastcolor=DCMBlue` for all cases where the background isn't `DCMBlue`. Is it possible to change the contrast colour just in the table?

Comment: @pdoak Have you even tried it?  `\startplacetable \setupinteraction[contrastcolor=red] ... \stopplacetable`